# Invoking an Apex method from a Lightning Web Component (LWC) is throwing an exception with the message 'sObject not supported'

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, experience-cloud

I've created a Lightning Web Component (LWC) that is embedded within an experience site page. In this LWC, I'm using the connectedCallback hook to retrieve a set of records from a custom object through an imperative Apex call. However, the Apex class is generating an error stating "sObject type 'Custom_Object__c' is not supported".

-> I've verified that the object and field permissions have been appropriately assigned to the community user.

'Custom_Object__c'
Object permissions => [Read, Create, Edit, Delete]

Fields permission => editable and readable for all fields.

OWD

**Custom_Object__c**

Default internal access: controlled by parent

Default External access: controlled by parent

**Parent Object**

Default internal access: private

Default External access: private

```java
public with sharing class LWCController {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Custom_Object__c> getCustomObjectRecords() {
    try {
       return [SELECT Id FROM Custom_Object__c LIMIT 1];
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

```js
import getCustomObjectRecords from '@salesforce/apex/LWCController.getCustomObjectRecords';

connectedCallback() {
  getCustomObjectRecords()
  .then(result => {
     // do something...
  }}
  .catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
   })
}
```

**I am getting above error when I loggin as Community user, and when I am in builder I don't get this error.**

Could someone provide insights into the reason behind encountering this error?